# How to convert a column of numbers into a date in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe contains a column for dates. It looks like this:

```
Index    Date
 0       12018
 1      102018
 2       32018
 3      122018
 4      112019
 5       32019
 6       42019
```

The last four numbers show the year and the first (two) the month.
I want to change the column to:

```
- 01-01-2018 
- 01-01-2018 
- 01-10-2018 
- 01-03-2018
...
```

or even better to a datetime format.

I've tried this function, which displays:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

```
def adjust_date(dataset_in, col_name):
day = "01"
for col in col_name:
    if len(col_name)>5:
        month = col_name[0:1]
        year = col_name[2:5]
    else:
        month = col_name[0]
        year = col_name[1:4]

    result = year + "-" + month + "-" + day 
return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with a specified [format](http://strftime.org/) should be enough:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%Y')
print (df)
   Index       Date
0      0 2018-01-01
1      1 2018-10-01
2      2 2018-03-01
3      3 2018-12-01
4      4 2019-11-01
5      5 2019-03-01
6      6 2019-04-01

print (df.dtypes)
Index             int64
Date     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Thank you @Vivek Kalyanarangan for solution - add [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for custom `string` format (but lost datetimes):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m%Y').dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print (df)
   Index        Date
0      0  01-01-2018
1      1  01-10-2018
2      2  01-03-2018
3      3  01-12-2018
4      4  01-11-2019
5      5  01-03-2019
6      6  01-04-2019

print (df.dtypes)
Index     int64
Date     object
dtype: object

print (df['Date'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
5    <class 'str'>
6    <class 'str'>
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Except OP also wants conversion from `%m%Y` to something like `%02d-%02m-%Y`

Comment: @AGNGazer - It seems pandas correct parse it, do you think not?

Comment: "*Explicit is better than implicit*" - So I would recommend `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%M%Y').dt.strftime('%M-%d-%Y')`

Comment: @AGN Gazer - Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. I hope I was accurate in preserving original intention.

Comment: @AGNGazer - Absolutely :) Small gift

Comment: @jezrael yes highlighting the fact that having `strftime` will lose the datetime cast was a good move. Upvoted!

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan - thank you, I also changed `M` to `m` for months :)