# How to convert string to datetime without days in pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

For example `issue_d` column in dataframe is string, `df['issue_d'] = 'Dec-2012'`

I want to convert the string to datetime type not string type: `2012-12`, how to do that?

I use

```
[datetime.strptime(x, '%b-%Y') for x in df.issue_d]
```

But I get as result 2012-12.

How can I get a result without days, and save it into a database by using mysql and sqlalchemy? I create a column issue_d with DateTime() type in my database.
I want to insert the df['issue_d'] into that table.

[Table created using sqlalchemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKk9N.png)

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date object with year and month only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425133/date-object-with-year-and-month-only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a column of numbers into a date in a dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503290/how-to-convert-a-column-of-numbers-into-a-date-in-a-dataframe-in-python)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50503324, especially second part of the answer showing how to use `strftime()` and links to the documentation.

Comment: I believe that mysql does not support month-year values as a date format. See the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

```
ex = pd.to_datetime('Dec-2012')
str(ex.year) + "-" + str(ex.month)
```

and with a series

```
series = pd.Series(["Dec-2012", "Nov-2013"])
series = pd.to_datetime(series)
series.apply(lambda x: str(x.year) + "-" + str(x.month))
```

you can also use

```
series.dt.to_period('M')
```

Check the pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: I want the data type is datetime not string type.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, here is one way:

Starting from a dataframe `df`:

```
>>> df
    issue_d
0  Dec-2012
1  Jan-2013
```

First, convert to datetime, then apply `strftime`:

```
df['issue_d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_d'])
df['issue_d'] = df['issue_d'].dt.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))

>>> df
   issue_d
0  2012-12
1  2013-01
```

Note that it's now a string representation of your date, but because you want a formatted date, I think it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
months = {
        'Jan' : 1,
        'Feb' : 2,
        'Mar' : 3,
        'Apr' : 4,
        'May' : 5,
        'Jun' : 6,
        'Jul' : 7,
        'Aug' : 8,
        'Sep' : 9, 
        'Oct' : 10,
        'Nov' : 11,
        'Dec' : 12
}

temp = df['issue_d']
temp.split('-')
return temp[1] + '-' + str(months[temp[0]])
```

Given the string 'Dec-2012' this should return 2012-12

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime("DEC-2012", '%b-%Y'),'%Y-%m')
```

Comment: The result is string type not datetime

Comment: I am wondering the usecase for having a datetime object without day and also the format of field should be datetime.

Comment: I need to merge two dataframe on datetime, and also need to insert it to the table that I created in database, when I do some query, I will do some operation on the datetime.

Comment: Does any of the existing fields in db contain only year-month format which has the datatype of date/datetime?

Comment: no, when I insert the datetime into db, it will convert the datetime with year, month and days (all days are 01).

Comment: Then have a the same format here with 01 as days and convert the string to datetime. Is it not what you want?